# 11 month old doesn't want to be away from mom or dad

Tags: discipline, first-time

My son is 11 months and he is our first baby. My husband leaves him in the daycare for about an hour so my husband can do the things he needs to do - i work at daytime. The problem is when we leave him to the daycare he kept crying and crying, and that is the reason why my husband can't do the things he needs to do because the daycare had to call him to pacify the baby. Our son isn't like that when we are with him, he is friendly and sociable but doesn't like it when he is alone. How can we handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Is this the first time that he's been away from you without anyone who he's familiar with?

Comment: How is he at bedtime?

Comment: @Catija we had been doing this for 3 weeks

Comment: @Gryphoenix we have terrible bedtime moments. There are times that he sleeps all through the night and times that wakes up every 2 or 3 am, sleeps 2 hours then wakes up again to see me go to work, then takes a nap before going to the daycare

Comment: @Marj hm...we have similar issues and right now, one of us sleeps in the room with our daughter with the idea that we would gradually work ourselves out as she learns to self soothe.

Comment: It is almost impossible to give you an answer. Perhaps there is another solution for daycare.  If there are other parents in the neighbourhood, you could give each other time breaks. Many children have separation issues but I cannot say that is what is happening. Is he weaned? Many children like the smell of mum and complain when they are in places that smell 'wrong.' Again, I can only guess.

Comment: @WillowRex I feed him, he isn't weaned yet. I am planning to wean him maybe this year after his 1st birthday.

Comment: So, in my limited experience (I am an adoptive parent), many babies just like the smell of the breast milk  and even though we do not know it is there, he knows when it is not. I am in bed today --I had minor surgery, but will see if I can find links. A sitter might work better until he is weaned. That said, daycares should be able to cope with crying infants, and if you like the centre, toughing it out is still an option.

Comment: No, sorry, cannot make this device link. Try googling, "baby like the smells of mom breast milk", there are tons of sites with info.

Comment: @WillowRex thank you for the info aww, you should rest :) hope you feel better soon

Comment: @Marj Hi Marj, May i know if you are aware of the daycare, How do they take care of your son?

Perhaps they are not good.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical if not normal. You have many options, but I'll pick what are possibly the top 3:

3) **Keep trying until your baby is comfortable with it**. This may take months, but most daycares can tell you when things are getting better or worse.

2) **Trade off childcare duties with your husband so he has free time at night**. This is awfully tough on you, though.

1) **Hire a sitter for inside the home.** A babysitter is often less than daycare for that kind of time frame and probably more flexible. Your baby will be in a comfort zone, and if things are bad, your husband will be around. Finding the right sitter might be difficult, but a retired neighbor or a high school student coming home from school could work.

Comment: My concern is with the daycare. From my experience (30 years in a classroom next door to the toddler and infant daycare classes) many/most children have some trouble with the transition from the home environment to the daycare. If the daycare cannot cope, there can only be a few reasons. 1) The child is seriously more upset than is usual and the daycare is fearful for his health. Or, 2) the daycare is incompetent. Either of these are a big concern, but only the parent can decide. I think it is more likely that Dad called to check and was told son was crying -- which is normal but hard on Dad.